# Get value of child node in xml from Bing Maps API in c#

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to access values in an XML response to Bing Maps API.  I'm trying to access the Latitude and Longitude of the location. My code seems like it should work fine, however the value of `locations` isn't a latitude value.  I am getting a response in XML, but maybe I should use JSON instead.

code

```
private void RequestCompleted(IAsyncResult result)
{
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)result.AsyncState;
    var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(result);
    StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

    try
    {
        XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(stream);

        var responseXml = xdoc.Descendants("ResourceSets");
        var locations = xdoc.Descendants("GeocodePoint").Elements("Latitude");

        var whatthehell = locations;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error" + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: you could simply deserialize the `Xml` and access the values as srtongly typed properties.

Comment: Eventually you could request for `JSON` data and use `JSON.Net` to parse and access the properties.

Comment: This is not a duplicate.  I looked at the other post and none of those solutions worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a namspace issue.  See code below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(FILENAME, Encoding.UTF8);

            XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(stream);
            XElement root = xdoc.Root;
            XNamespace ns = root.GetDefaultNamespace();

            List<XElement> responseXml = xdoc.Descendants(ns + "ResourceSets").ToList();
            List<XElement> locations = xdoc.Descendants(ns + "GeocodePoint").Elements(ns + "Latitude").ToList();

        }
    }
}
```